# Flash is blocked by chrome - can I see the flash that would have been executed?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

[image]

It's just me being nosy - I see that sometimes on wordpress admin and other places have a flash plugin code snippet running....I see it's adobe flash player that's blocked.

How can I see the actual flash file itself so I can examine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on the page and choose "View Page Source", then search for .swf you will see the path to the file.

You can then use any download tool to download that file.

Comment: simple and so obvious why didn't I bother trying that?!?  okay so I find that it was flowplayer.swf